# Looking for iptables binary for Android 2.3 ARM platform?

Tags: android, proxy, platform, iptables

I am trying to setup a proxy on an Android device using iptables. We are using Androd 2.3. I don't see iptables in emulator or in our platform build.
Where can I download a prebuilt iptables binary (and all supporting libs it needs) for setting up a NAT like rule?
I like to run it like this eventually:
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 24 -j REDIRECT --to-port 7060

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any pre-built iptables binary that android is supposed to have. That said, you could probably build iptabels for you device using the source code found [here](http://www.netfilter.org/licensing.html).

Comment: Just wondering if there is one already built. I use emulator on MacOSX. I am trying to save myself time setting up the whole android repo etc to build this tool.